# How can render different navigations when changing controllers in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a side panel menu which calls different controller methods within my asp.net mvc 4 app c#.

There is a top menu which needs to change depending on what controller is entered.

I wanted to know what is a good method to change the top navigation depending on what side navigation is action is pressed.

An example is if i press Admin on the left menu then the top navigation will only show admin options. If I press Contacts then the top menu will change to show crud methods for contacts.

Any replies would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about the issue i decided on the following implementation: I created two partial views which had different menu items dependent on which controller is selected.

Steps I took:

1. Created a ViewModel for my layout with one property:

   public class LayoutViewModel
   {
       private string _menuNav;

   ```
   public string MenuNav
   {
       get { return _menuNav; }
       set { _menuNav = value != null ? value : "_HomeMenu"; }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Then added a base class on my homeviewmodel (note no other types are defined as its for demo purposes)

   public class HomeIndexViewModel: LayoutViewModel
   {

}

1. Create an Attribute allowing me to add this new attribute to the controller so it gets the correct navigation partial view.

   public class MenuActionAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
   {
       private string _MenuName;

   ```
   public MenuActionAttribute(string MenuName)
   {
       _MenuName = MenuName;
   }

   public override void  OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
   {
       var lvm = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model as LayoutViewModel;

       lvm.MenuNav = _MenuName;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Added attribute to the controller action methods

   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       [MenuAction("_HomeMenu")]
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           var hm = new HomeIndexViewModel();

   ```
       return View(hm);
   }

   [MenuAction("_HRMenu")]
   public ActionResult About()
   {
       var hm = new HomeIndexViewModel();

       return View(hm);
   }
   ```

   }

Hope this helps.

There are other ways of doing this but all have their pro's and con's. Just got to make the decision and be prepared to change if it does not work properly.